# UWP : Transitions not being clipped?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a problem in which I've got transitions such as `EntranceThemeTransition` on some controls which means they appear in a pleasant manner. However, these transitions seem to ignore the regular clip of the containing control, i.e. the `ListView` or `ScrollViewer`.

It means that for a split second my elements appear outside of the `ListView` as they are animating, but once the animation is over, the elements respect the clipping path and every works great.

Basically, I want the transition animations to respect the clip of the containing element, just as they do once the clip is over. It's not just `ListView` that has the problem, `FlipView` seems to also.

For a split second, I'll see the animation happen inside a `FlipViewItem` which *isn't* the current one! I don't see how that can't be a bug in `FlipView`.

Anyway, is there any way to get those transition animations to respect the clip? It's very ugly to see a split second of animation outside of the `ListView` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of `ListView` you can't influence the behavior too much, because that is how the transition works. You can however tweak it using `EntranceThemeTransition`'s `FromHorizontalOffset` and `FromVerticalOffset` properties.

In case of `FlipView` it is not a bug per se. `FlipView` is basically a `ScrollViewer` with special behavior (only one item visible at a time), but the items preload even then (especially the immediate previous and immediate next). That means when the page loads, the `FlipView` appears and its children get loaded and you might see a glimpse of the transitions outside the item currently displayed. To circumvent this you have several options:

- Transition only the first displayed item's children
- Add `EntranceThemeTransition` only to the `FlipView` itself
- Create a custom animation using `Storyboard` or implicit animations and start it manually when the flip view item changes

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up kind of fixing by accident. I placed a "please wait" pane over the flipview to show loading progress, and this seem to have cured the problem. I don't really know why, but I'm not complaining.